# Как можно определить с каким обьектом или слоем соприкасается игрок?

Tags: unity3d

Есть игрок, лестница и пол. Мне нужно, чтобы при условии, что игрок стоит на полу, я мог проходить сквозь лестницу, но когда я нахожусь возле лестницы и нажимаю кнопку движения вверх, то лестница стала активной. Я сделал подобное условие:

```
        if (Player == DownStairs)
        {
            Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(playerObj, stairsObj, true);
            Debug.Log("ОТКЛЮЧИЛИ ЛЕСТНИЦУ");
        }
        else if(Player==DownStairs&&Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(playerObj, stairsObj, false);
            Debug.Log("ВКЛЮЧИЛИ ЛЕСТНИЦУ");
        }
```

Здесь условие не работает.
Но меняю условие с `Player == DownStairs` на `Player && DownStairs`, тогда лестница начинает работать. Но не так как нужно. Ведь условие не определяет, что игрок находиться на полу, а просто "игрок и пол". Как осуществить мою задумку?

Comment: Ах да `playerObj = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Player");
        stairsObj = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Collider");`

Comment: Если вы хотите что-то добавить к вопросу, вам следует воспользоваться опцией "править" (кнопка под вопросом)

Comment: То есть формально вам нужно, чтобы игрок мог проходить сквозь лестницу **всегда**, однако если он ее касается **И** зажата кнопка передвижения вверх, то он ползет вверх? Если да, то можно сделать лестницу триггером. А при нажатии кнопки движения вверх, просто проверять **пересекается ли в данный момент игрок с лестницей**. Это можно делать, например, через [OverlapCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OverlapCollider.html)

Comment: На тот момент еще не было кнопки" добавить") У меня лестница не вертикально стоят, а 45 градусов. как лестница во многоэтажках к примеру. И когда я делал через тригер, то поднимался нормально, но начиная спускаться, я просто падал. Но функция интересная, сейчас буду в нее вникать. Спасибо

Comment: Не вижу основного тезиса в вашем комментарии. Если он заключается в том, что с триггерами у вас не получилось, то это не потому, что триггеры плохие, а потому, что у вас не получилось (извините за тавтологию). Я так понимаю, для ползания по лестнице у вас какая-то анимация, которая может лишь остановиться на середине? Как тогда с нее можно упасть? Как вообще у вас реализовано само поднятие-спуск по лестнице?

Comment: https://sun9-25.userapi.com/impg/7qSAfFzrRYw7F4yBVJS-j-yyzQTOZARi9kmlrw/AqMeK9AsuLc.jpg?size=1920x1080&quality=96&sign=aa99bf5966601a65d2687e59eacaee5d&type=album   Нормально  Чтото сюда он не пишется. Такой код у меня.
https://sun9-82.userapi.com/impg/a-PQVYEr-PeF_U00kLRkoVeuOCsevUv0w7Ym5w/6BeTEMvu_Yo.jpg?size=1920x1080&quality=96&sign=923983aa02872e417b10969aeb7e6c64&type=album

Comment: Я Думал сделать, если игрок касается к лестнице и нажимает вверх - тогда лестница активна и можно подниматься. Так же если игрок касается лестницы сверху и находиться на ней пока не спуститься и не каснется пола, она тоже будет активна. Но чтото я так и не понял как это сделать и мне кажется, я этим себе только усложню все и есть способ проще, о котором я не знаю.